# Get rid of empty rows in eCharts custom series

Tags: echarts

I have a custom series, which renders a collection of 'undefined' or empty rows in my chart. Is there a way to get rid of them? See screenshot:

[image]

**Update**

Max set to 100 and never got updated based on data set filtering:

```js
yAxis: {
    data: null,
    axisTick: {
      show: false
    },
    splitLine: {
      show: true
    },
    axisLine: {
      show: true
    },
    axisLabel: {
      show: true,
      formatter: (value: any, index: number) => {
        return value;
      }
    },
    min: 0,
    max: this.chartAssets.length - 1, // this line here cased this behavior
    inverse: true,
}
```

Comment: Dude, have the decency, save someone else's time and show the code with data on jsfiddle first.

Comment: @SergeyFedorov didn't feel like it warranty a coding sample as it a was a general question. problem was on the y-axis, i specified a 100 for maximum, which never got updated by filtering code.

Comment: You need to show the complete chart to reproduce bug. Otherwise, I need to not only understand the problem, but also figure out how to reproduce it.

Comment: @SergeyFedorov fair comment. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was actually a developer mishap.

We forgot to update the maximum value with the changes from user selected filtering.

If anyone else runs into this, simply update the maximum value (read more about it [here](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.max)), according to the length of the data set you, your applying to the chart.

```js
yAxis: {
    max: this.chartAssets.length - 1, // update accordingly 
}
```